# How to remove a range of lines from csv file?

Tags: python, csv, line

I Would like to remove lines 3 to 15 from file 'Database.csv'. Please see my code below, this code is works only for one line i added `range`, but is didn't work. `;/`

```
filename = 'Database.csv'
line_to_delete = [3:15]
initial_line = 1
file_lines = {}

with open(filename) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

for line in content:
    file_lines[initial_line] = line.strip()
    initial_line += 1

f = open(filename, "w")
for line_number, line_content in file_lines.items():
    if line_number != line_to_delete:
        f.write('{}\n'.format(line_content))

f.close()
print('Deleted line: {}'.format(line_to_delete))
```

Comment: This code won't work at all: `line_to_delete = [3:15]` is not valid Python. Why don't you just write the output if `line_number < 3 or line_number > 15`?

Comment: If you change [3:15] to for e.g 3. They will been work

Comment: I'm not sure what that means or why you would post code that deliberately has syntax errors. Changing `[3:15]` to `3` won't work either. It will now be valid syntactically, but it won't do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use csv library for doing this.

```
import csv
file=open("Database.csv",'rb')
final_file=open("Database_edited",'wb')
writer=csv.writer(final_file)
line_no=1   # for knowing the line number
for row in csv.reader(file):
    if(line_no<=3 or line_no>=15):
        writer.writerow(row)
    line_no=line_no+1
file.close()
final_file.close()
```

This way Database_edited will have your required file

Comment: Thank you, but i got a error "AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'write'" :/

Comment: Sorry, the function name was writerow() not write(), i have corrected it, now it will work

Comment: Thank you, billant !

Comment: I'm tested on mac and small file csv, but if im trying on big database is 500k records aprox.50MB i got error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 6, in <module>
    for row in csv.reader(file):
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in
text mode?)

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: When you open the file, you can specify encoding as well. I don't know know what might be the encoding of the file you are trying to open but if you give encoding ="utf-8" in open function, it might work OR you can change parameter 'rb' tp 'r' to not read as binary.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #Tested code on Python 3.6
import csv

filename = r'C:\Users\91852\Desktop\New folder (2)\lines.csv'
start_skip_row = 3
stop_skip_row = 13


def readCSVFile(file_name: str, start: int, stop: int) -> list:
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file_content:
        data_after_deletion = [line.replace('\n', '') for idx, line in enumerate(file_content) if
                               not start - 1 <= idx < stop]
        print(data_after_deletion)
        return data_after_deletion


def writeCSVFile(data: list) -> None:
    with open('file_after_deletion', 'w', newline='') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
        writer.writerows(data)


data_after_deletion = readCSVFile(filename, start_skip_row, stop_skip_row)
writeCSVFile(data_after_deletion)
```

Comment: Thank you, but i got a error :( "File "script.py", line 8
    def readCSVFile(file_name: str, start: int, stop: int) -> list:"

Comment: @Dashiphone added 'r' in front of filename

Comment: it's working fine on my system.Can you share error log

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way to do using the `csv` module and the `range()` function:

```
mport csv

filename = 'Database.csv'
startline, endline = 3, 15  # Inclusive.

with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as f:
    content = [row for i,row in enumerate(csv.reader(f), 1)
                    if i not in range(startline, endline+1)]

filename2 = 'Database2.csv'  # Write to different file for testing.
with open(filename2, 'w', newline='') as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows(content)

print('lines deleted')
```